# Difference between "free variable" and "free occurrence of a variable" in context of lambda calculus

Tags: substitution, lambda-calculus, free-variable, bound-variable

Is there any difference between free variable and free occurrence of a variable in context of lambda calculus? If yes, then please explain with an example or two. 
Actually I was going through the conversion rules for lambda expression where I came across the following line:

> In stating the conversion rules the notation `E[E'/V]` is used to mean the result of substituting `E'` for each free occurrence of `V` in `E`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's take the term T:

```
t\q\p\ (t x (x\ q x) (p q x)
```

(where x\ t means lambda x.t - this is Lambda-Prolog notation)

There is *one* free variable: x, and *four* bound variables, one of which is also named x. But the two "x" are **not** the *same* variable (in the sense that the term can be alpha renamed to  `t\q\p\ (t x (y\ q y) (p q x)`
but not, for example, to: `t\q\p\ (t x (y\ q y) (p q y)`

In the term T above, there are **two** free occurrences of the variable x and one bound occurrence of another variable, also named x.

Now, if your question is "can there be, in the *same term*, both free occurrences and bound occurrences of the **same** variable, be it bound or free?", I don't think so.